# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView smoothScroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I have a recyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. I know this is not a good practice, but I need  a listener for the scroll.

The listener consists on notify when the user reached the final of the recyclerView. This have a gridLayoutManager with 3 grids and the number of rows visible depends of the size of the screen.

Everything works but the smoothScroll.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedGalleryAll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/galleryAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is how is working my app.

[image: Example screen gif]

Comment: what do you exactly want ?? smooth scroll ??

Comment: yes, only smoothScroll without losing the listener of the nestedScrollView

Comment: i have updated my answer..

Comment: btw why do you need the listener for nested scrollview ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..  `recylerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` in your activity....
**Edit** To notify user if he reached end..use this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new      RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() { 

   @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
   {  

  LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager.class.cast(recyclerView.getLayoutManager()); 
   int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();

   int lastVisible = 
    layoutManager.
    findLastVisibleItemPosition();                     boolean
 endHasBeenReached 
 = lastVisible + 5 
    >= totalItemCount;
 if (totalItemCount > 0 && endHasBeenReached) 

 { //you have reached to the bottom of your recycler view } } });
```

Comment: If I do that my listener is disabled. I need that listener to update the items of the recyclerView when the user get to the end of it.

Comment: i have updated the code..add scroll listener to the recyclerview..when last item visible `notify user` or fetch the next items..

Comment: test it and let me know if you have any other problems

Comment: it worked!, Thanks. I'm using Kotlin and I had problems to translate LinearLayoutManager.class.cast(recyclerView.getLayoutManager()), but I translated to LinearLayoutManager::class.java.cast(recyclerView.layoutManager) and worked.

Thanks to this I'm not using a NestedScrollView anymore.